# How do I determine the path to AWS Buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS. I have a website and I would like to host my larger images on AWS. I have successfully created a bucket and can access that bucket via FTP but I do not know how to determine the URL for the contents of that bucket so I can reference the images on my website.

I have tried: https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/imagename.jpg

and I have tried https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/imagename.jpg

But I get errors on both.

What is the correct path?

Thank you.

Comment: If you see errors, always include the error text and error code, as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Click on the bucket. Go to properties, scroll to the bottom, under 'static website hosting', click edit then enable.

Once saved, you will be provided with a 'bucket website endpoint' (i.e. a url to access your files).

Under the 'permissions' tab, you may also need to allow public access to the objects in the bucket by adding a bucket policy like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1517754859350",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGetObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET-NAME-HERE/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

AWS S3 objects can be accessed at `https://{bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/{key}`.

You should have seen an error message in the webpage.
But before that, make sure that the object in the bucket is public. Go to the bucket, change the object to make it public.

But best option is to create a CloudFront distribution. Otherwise accessing S3 bucket directly is costly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other two answers posted, which helped move me in the right direction I was able to get more insights and discovered that the easiest way to provide read-only access to bucket assets is to set an ACL that is domain specific so that only requests that come from the designated URL will have read access to the contents of the bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "https://example.com/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The URL or path to the resources is provided in the Control Panel when you add objects to the bucket and is listed as the

> Object URL

.

Comment: Requests that *claim* to come from the designated domain will have read access. Referer spoofing is trivial.

Comment: @jarmod It looks like AWS is your specialty and you have shown particular interest in this post. Would you mind adding your perspective to this issue since I have not fully resolved it. I thought the above answer was solid, but unless I individually mark objects as public they cannot be accessed. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Typically you would configure S3 static website hosting, create a CloudFront distribution, configure a bucket policy that permits s3:GetObject to the CloudFront's OAI (so that direct bucket access is not allowed outside of CloudFront), and then, as needed, configure AWS WAF on the CloudFront Distribution so that you can control access via referer, IP ranges, geo match and more. The simpler option, that you're currently using, can be improved by allowing s3:GetObject to principal * (modulo referer and any other conditions) in an S3 bucket policy, so you don't have to set an ACL on each object.

Comment: @jarmod What is missing from the ACL code in my answer above? That is preferable to setting up a static website listing with CloudFront distribution, etc. Thanks.

Comment: I don’t recall if it was originally written this way (my client doesn’t seem to show edit history) but what you have currently is an S3 bucket policy, not an ACL. ACLs are legacy mechanism that you generally should not use. So, it looks ok as long as you’re happy with all clients having get access if they present the relevant referer header. Be aware that you’re paying for all network out, except to AWS compute in the same region, and you have no caching or WAF to mitigate abuse here.